# Description text moves to the top of the product page

Tags: magento2

Description text which contains a span tag, moves to the top of the page.

Example:
Description text in back end - "Buy this beautiful (span class="blue">)blue(/span) dress today. Free shipping."

In front end the description text displays correctly. However, at the very top of the product page, the text following the span tag is also displayed:

"blue dress today. Free shipping."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix at this link. I just had the same issue and I fixed it doing the following : https://mage2.pro/t/topic/161

Credits goes to the author : `Dmitry FedyukNov 4 1`

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yen9jnf1187qvu0/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202016-02-29%2023.28.51.png?dl=0

To fix the issue replace it with the following one:

```
$this->pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr(strip_tags($product->getDescription()), 0, 255));
```